# Swig python - c++ how to use type int8_t

Tags: c++, python, swig, ctypes

I have a C function that takes as paramenter an 8 bit integer

```
int8_t foo( int8_t x );
```

I would like to call this function from my python code using a swig interface but int8_t type do not exists in python.
In order to have this kind of types exists a python module called numpy.
Even using this yet I do not manage to make the 2 comunicating.

Do you know if there is any way of defining such a type in the SWIG interfacve in order to be able to use it from python??

int8_t is just an example... i have to do the same for signed/unsigned from 8 up to 64 bits

Thanks in advance,
S.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In your SWIG interface file use:

```
%include "stdint.i"
```

*before* you first use `uint8_t`. SWIG will then apply an appropriate typemap for you.